# removeClass working in console.log but not in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm developing a web page with a demanding update algorithm and I want to place a spinner while loading. I want the spinner to show only while loading and then disappear when done.

I just defined a class .hidden with "display: none" and used jQuery to select my div.spinner and remove/add the class hidden.

```
function startSpinner() {
    console.log("spinner running");
    console.log($(".spinner"));   
    $(".spinner.hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    console.log($(".spinner"));
}

function stopSpinner() {
    console.log("spinner stopped");
    console.log($(".spinner"));   
    $(".spinner").addClass("hidden");
    console.log($(".spinner"));
}

$(".btn").click((e) => {
    startSpinner();
  for(let i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
    // some hard work
  }
  stopSpinner();
})
```

I expect the spinner to pop out when I click and then disappear when for(..) is done, but it doesn't seem like it.

Even if in the console everything is working fine:

```
spinner running 
Object { 0: div.spinner.hidden, length: 1, prevObject: Object(1) } 
Object { 0: div.spinner, length: 1, prevObject: Object(1) } 
spinner stopped 
Object { 0: div.spinner, length: 1, prevObject: Object(1) } 
Object { 0: div.spinner.hidden, length: 1, prevObject: Object(1) }
```

Why the spinner is not popping up in the DOM? And what can I do to reach my goal?

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m1ax4nsg/11/

(the for cycle length is enough for my browser to wait some time, feel free to increase the number of cycles if it is not for yours)

Comment: I have fiddled with your code and this is what I found, perhaps it is machine related => I disabled the `stopSpinner` function and realized that it took the spinner a long time before showing up, which means that the spinner never gets to show before it is hidden again. Possible reason - stack overflowed ;) I think @smashed-potatoes ' answer should work just fine. If it doesn't, you can play around with the `setTimeout` delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the spinner show up is because in your example your CPU consuming work is synchronous with and blocking the showing and hiding of your spinner (the JS thread runs all of your code in sequence and doesn't allow for the DOM to update between).

If your real world code is async you shouldn't have this problem, or if it is JS CPU intensive you can set a timeout before starting it to give the DOM time to update, i.e.:

```
...

function cpuIntensiveWork() {
  for(let i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
    // some hard work
  }
  stopSpinner();
}

$(".btn").click((e) => {
  startSpinner();
  setTimeout(cpuIntensiveWork, 10);
})

...
```

Comment: It worked, thousands of thank you! I suspected was something related to synchronization, the logs in the console confused me though. Probably it was updated internally but it waited the code to end to display all changes and then it was too late, could it be? Thanks again

Comment: @silviajoy Exactly, the code all runs but the JS thread blocks the UI from updating until it has finished at which point it is too late. Glad it worked for you, happy to help!